# Pipe program output into a protected file using sudo

Tags: sudo, pipe

I want to do the following:

```
$ echo "secrets" > protected_file
```

But the the problem is, I don't have file permissions for "protected_file", so I try the following:

```
$ sudo echo "secrets" > protected_file
```

But that doesn't work either because only the "echo" portion of the command is executed under sudo.

What's the correct way to do this?

-Geoffrey Lee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "secrets" > protected_file'
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `echo 'secrets' | sudo tee filename > /dev/null` or `echo 'secrets' | sudo tee -a filename > /dev/null` if you wish to append.